# Showing Qt Virtual Keyboard in the same window as the application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

Here is my question, I want to use qtvirtual keyboard for a touch screen app. When I call it, it pops up on a different window. How do I get the keyboard to pop up on the same window?

If I have tried using QQuick view and QqmlApplicationEngine (the latter doesn't even load the keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's [detected automatically](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html#integration-method), but if you're on desktop it may choose Desktop Integration.

[This page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html) has an example of how to configure your application's .pro file to choose a different QML file depending on which platform you're building on/for:

```
disable-desktop|android-embedded|!isEmpty(CROSS_COMPILE)|qnx {
    DEFINES += MAIN_QML=\\\"basic-b2qt.qml\\\"
} else {
    DEFINES += MAIN_QML=\\\"Basic.qml\\\"
}
```

[basic-b2qt.qml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-basic-b2qt-qml.html) from that example can be used for Application Integration (i.e. showing the keyboard in the same window):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings 2.2
import "content"

Item {
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    Item {
        id: appContainer
        width: Screen.width < Screen.height ? parent.height : parent.width
        height: Screen.width < Screen.height ? parent.width : parent.height
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        rotation: Screen.width < Screen.height ? 90 : 0
        Basic {
            id: virtualKeyboard
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: inputPanel.top
            handwritingInputPanelActive: handwritingInputPanel.active
        }

        /*  Handwriting input panel for full screen handwriting input.

            This component is an optional add-on for the InputPanel component, that
            is, its use does not affect the operation of the InputPanel component,
            but it also can not be used as a standalone component.

            The handwriting input panel is positioned to cover the entire area of
            application. The panel itself is transparent, but once it is active the
            user can draw handwriting on it.
        */
        HandwritingInputPanel {
            z: 79
            id: handwritingInputPanel
            anchors.fill: parent
            inputPanel: inputPanel
            Rectangle {
                z: -1
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "black"
                opacity: 0.10
            }
        }

        /*  Container area for the handwriting mode button.

            Handwriting mode button can be moved freely within the container area.
            In this example, a single click changes the handwriting mode and a
            double-click changes the availability of the full screen handwriting input.
        */
        Item {
            z: 99
            visible: handwritingInputPanel.enabled && Qt.inputMethod.visible
            anchors { left: parent.left; top: parent.top; right: parent.right; bottom: inputPanel.top; }
            HandwritingModeButton {
                id: handwritingModeButton
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.margins: 10
                floating: true
                flipable: true
                width: 76
                height: width
                state: handwritingInputPanel.state
                onClicked: handwritingInputPanel.active = !handwritingInputPanel.active
                onDoubleClicked: handwritingInputPanel.available = !handwritingInputPanel.available
            }
        }

        /*  Keyboard input panel.

            The keyboard is anchored to the bottom of the application.
        */
        InputPanel {
            id: inputPanel
            z: 89
            y: appContainer.height
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            states: State {
                name: "visible"
                /*  The visibility of the InputPanel can be bound to the Qt.inputMethod.visible property,
                    but then the handwriting input panel and the keyboard input panel can be visible
                    at the same time. Here the visibility is bound to InputPanel.active property instead,
                    which allows the handwriting panel to control the visibility when necessary.
                */
                when: inputPanel.active
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: inputPanel
                    y: appContainer.height - inputPanel.height
                }
            }
            transitions: Transition {
                id: inputPanelTransition
                from: ""
                to: "visible"
                reversible: true
                enabled: !VirtualKeyboardSettings.fullScreenMode
                ParallelAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation {
                        properties: "y"
                        duration: 250
                        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                    }
                }
            }
            Binding {
                target: InputContext
                property: "animating"
                value: inputPanelTransition.running
            }
            AutoScroller {}
        }

        Binding {
            target: VirtualKeyboardSettings
            property: "fullScreenMode"
            value: appContainer.height > 0 && (appContainer.width / appContainer.height) > (16.0 / 9.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the qml file. But it pops up in it's own window.